# ANTLR tokens ambiguity

Tags: antlr, lexer

I would like to parse string like "Lorem ipsum AND dolor AND sit amet consectetur"

I need two tokens

1. word "AND"
2. any other word

Using antlr2, if I define tokens like

```
AND_WORD: "AND" ;
ANY_OTHER_WORD: ('0'..'9'|'a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_')+ ;
```

I'm getting "warning:lexical nondeterminism between rules"

How can I solve it? Should I somehow exclude AND_WORD from ANY_OTHER_WORD definition?

Comment: Why are you using ANTLR 2?

Comment: @Bart Kiers, because of transitive dependency, I use another library that depends on ANTLR 2

Comment: I recommend trying to use the latest version of ANTLR next to the old v2 dependency. I doubt anyone is still actively working with v2 *and* monitoring SO. Best of luck of course.